# Lookup value in values listed within one cell and show result from listed values within other cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I currently have 2 columns in Excel. Multiple rows of data with line breaks.

Data (space between values equals a line break (`CHAR(10)`):

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 3 59 89 158 123 | 15105540 0029803508 103138393 002281913 501847 1XJ5RP5QQ60 |

What I am trying to do is find which line the number '3' is on in coumn 1. Then I need the contents from cell 2 that is on that same line.

[image: My 2 cells]

I was thinking a VBA formula that finds how many line breaks are before the 3 in column 1 and then searches column 2 for that many X line breaks and then extracts the next 10 characters from column 2 into its own cell.

I don't know VBA, but I have tried writing multiple Excel formulas that arent really giving me the exact results I need

Comment: Some sample data would be useful

Comment: I think what you mean is to get the string on the nth line of column-2 (doesn't care how many character). Example : the found number 3 in col-1 is in the second line. In col-2, the second line is "1234567" ---> So you want something like a message box which saying _"the 2nd line of col-2 value is 1234567"_. Other example : the found number 123 in col-1 is in the 6th line. In col-2, the 6th line is "bla" ---> So you want something like a message box which saying _"the 6th line of col-2 value is bla"_. Please CMIIW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me  start with that the question was fairly unclear. You referenced the cell containing several strings separated by line breaks as being a column, so at first I thought a simple VLOOKUP (`=VLOOKUP(3,A:B,2,0)`) would suffice.

I edited the question a little to make that more clear (and also allows people to use the data, without having to retype it to be able to reproduce).

Then I saw tinazmu's answer and thought why complicate things that much for a simpel lookup. Than looking at the pictures in her(?) post I realized it calculated single cells containing line breaks.
Than looking back at your question I realized she spotted that very well.

Here's a version that would work without helper column. It does require Microsoft 365 or Excel 2021:

```
=LET(x, "3",
     a, TEXTSPLIT(A1,,CHAR(10)),
     b, TEXTSPLIT(B1,,CHAR(10)),
XLOOKUP(x,a,b)
     )
```

[image]

`LET` first declares names of strings/calculation results which we can refer to later in the actual formula.
In this case I declared the following:

> `x` is the value to be searched.
>
> `a` is the text in cell `A1` splitted by line breaks (Excel notation for line break: `CHAR(10)`).
>
> `b` is the text in cell `B1` spliited by line breaks.

Where `x` is a string (should be text) and `a` and `b` are both arrays of the separate strings per cell.

We can than use our formula - a simple XLOOKUP - referencing the declared names:

`XLOOKUP(x,a,b)`

This looks up value `x` in the `a`-array and returns the string found at the same position from the `b`-array.

You could also replace the search string for a cell value, for instance `E4`; to be able to change the search value without altering the formula. In this case it could be handy to make sure that if a number value is entered in that cell it will not result in an error while the value is actually found in the string.
*This happens because `TEXTSPLIT` is a text-function and therefore always returns text strings.*

So to avoid this we implement a `VALUETOTEXT` and it would look like this:

```
=LET(x, E4,
     a, TEXTSPLIT(A1,,CHAR(10)),
     b, TEXTSPLIT(B1,,CHAR(10)),
XLOOKUP(VALUETOTEXT(x),a,b)
     )
```

[image]

If you want to search a range instead of a single cell we have two options. join the  cell values in the range and split them the way described above:

```
=LET(x, E4,
     a, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,A1:A2),,CHAR(10)),
     b, TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,B1:B2),,CHAR(10)),
XLOOKUP(VALUETOTEXT(x),a,b)
     )
```

[image]

but this way the character limit for textjoin/textsplit would be reached if there would be more cells in the range.

If that's the case we can involve `LAMBDA`-helper `REDUCE`:

```
=LET(x,E4,
     a, DROP(REDUCE(0,A1:A2,LAMBDA(old,new,VSTACK(old,TEXTSPLIT(new,,CHAR(10))))),1),
     b, DROP(REDUCE(0,B1:B2,LAMBDA(old,new,VSTACK(old,TEXTSPLIT(new,,CHAR(10))))),1),
XLOOKUP(VALUETOTEXT(x),a,b)
     )
```

[image]

The `REDUCE`-function behaves like this:
you declare a start point and an array/range to "loop" through. You name these and these names can be used in a formula, just like we saw in the `LET` explanation at the start of the explanation of this post. The difference here is that we first mention the value/array/range (after `REDUCE(`) and name them afterwards (after `LAMBDA(`). Another difference is that we can store the calculation value of the previously calculated result and call that value in the next calculation of the same formula; like a loop.

In this case for `a` I used the following names:

> `old` for the starting point of REDUCE: `0` `
>
> `new` for the "loop" array/range: `A1:A2`

The function would start at `old`. So it takes value `0` and because combined with VSTACK it vertically stacks that to no value that's there. So it results in `0`. This result is now the replaced value for `old` and it'll now continue the same for the first value found in `new`. Which is the first found in the range `A1:A2`, being `A1`.

REDUCE will Vstack the `old` which resulted to `0` to the textsplit of the `new`, so the spill array of the textsplit of `A1`. and this becomes the array stored as `old`.

Next REDUCE will Vstack the `old` array to the new calculated spill array of the next in range: `A2`. And the next array for `old becomes the stack of` 0`& spill of textsplit of`A1`& spill of textsplit of`A2`. This would be the end value of REDUCE in this case, but if you have a larger range/array it would loop through it one by one and stack the results to one large array of strings.

Since REDUCE starts with `0` and this not being an actual value in your range, we use `DROP([REDUCE-result],1)` to remove/drop this value from the array.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful. Sorry for the horrible quesion. This worked perfectly for what I needed

Comment: Glad I could help. After all it was a nice problem to look into. Just curious, did you need to compare this for two cells only, or a range? In that case, which solution did you use?

Comment: I had a sheet with over 2000 rows I needed to do this to, I was able to use your first formula and drag it down across the whole thing. The '3' was in a diffrent spot in each cell, but it worked perfectly.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the 3 being in a different spot for each cell

Answer (score 1):

We can use FIND and SUBSTITUTE functions to do this, I extractred 5 chars from the other line, you need to adjust these to your sheet:

[image: If this is the data on my sheet]

[image: And the formulae]